# Nodejs Express Mongodb: How to execute mongo command upon user action.

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am using Express framework to make a web application. Suppose the user clicks a button in a page and I want to delete some data in the database. How is this achieved? Any recommendation/reading resource will be appreciated.

Comment: there are tonnes of example of node, mongodb with mongoose

Comment: a simple search in google helps you a lot, read https://zellwk.com/blog/crud-express-mongodb/